# CSRF implementation in a Spring + Wicket project

Tags: spring-security, csrf, wicket, csrf-token, wicket-1.5

We have to implement csrf in a legacy application which uses spring and wicket for frontend framework. To implement csrf we have tried two approaches:

Approach 1: upgraded spring security to version 4 so that csrf is enabled by default and we have added the hidden field in all the wicket forms.
But unfortunately we are getting 403 error after login:

This is html page:

```
<form wicket:id="Form" id="Form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" wicket:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" wicket:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <span id="feedback" wicket:id="feedback"/>
    <h2 align="left">Test Text</h2>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" class="form">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>Test</h4>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="required">*</span>
            </td>
            <td class="FieldName">
                <select wicket:id="Test"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="buttonpannel">
        <div class="right">
            <input wicket:id="submit" type="submit" value=" OK " readonly="readonly" style="width:80px;"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Approach 2: We have also tried to generate the token like using java and followed this [link](https://blog.eyallupu.com/2012/04/csrf-defense-in-spring-mvc-31.html). But the interceptor and the datavalue processor are not being called and we see no difference in the application after the implementation. This is our web.xml:

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="preAuthFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <!-- security:access-denied-handler error-page="/error/403" /-->
</security:http>
<bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>
<bean id="preAuthFilter" class="com.c.w.security.PreAuthFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="checkForPrincipalChanges" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
        <bean class="com.c.w.security.UserDetailsService"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref='preauthAuthProvider'/>
</security:authentication-manager>
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
<!-- Data Value Processor -->
<bean name="requestDataValueProcessor" class="com.c.w.csrf.CSRFRequestDataValueProcessor"/>
<!-- Interceptor handlers -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.c.w.csrf.CSRFHandlerInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

There is now way we are getting csrf to work in our application. We use wicket 1.5.10 version